# I'm having trouble solving finding the integral $\int (\sqrt[3]{x}(x-1)) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int (\sqrt[3]{x}(x-1)) dx$$

I think I can start off by making x-1 v'x and cube root x ux...?

Comment: For clarity, are you finding $$\int \sqrt[3]{x(x-1)} dx$$ By the way, here's [a reference for MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you might find useful, which is preferred for writing up and rendering your math text on this site.

Comment: Have you tried $x=\sec^2 t$?

Comment: I fixed the equation in the question!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply recall that $\sqrt [3] x = x^{1/3}$, distribute it to both terms in $(x-1)$, and use the power rule.

$$\int \sqrt[3]x (x-1)dx = \int x^{1/3}(x-1)dx = \int (x^{4/3} - x^{1/3})dx = \frac 3 7 x^{7/3} - \frac 3 4 x^{4/3} + C$$